# using matlab import wizard

Tags: database, matlab, import

I have made this data.txt file and imported it into matlab using import wizard. 
this is the result :

[image: Data Base]

This table is my data base and I want to search into it column wise (each variable). I used `strread`  as this lets me to search columns, for example : 
`var1=strread(VarName12(1,1),'%d',"delimiter','|')`
I wrote several lines of code using strread in a script and then run it. when I check the workspace var1 and other variables that included strread result are missing and typing them in command window gives me this : `Undefined function or variable 'End'.` I typed sttread in command window and used variables in data.txt and got the result but it doesn't work when I run my script. I can't understand what's the problem? ( I'm using matlab R2013a and there is warning that says : using strread is not recommende. use TEXTSCAN instead. I can't do the same with textscan also strread works properly when written in workspace ). I don't know what is the problem. can give a clue?

EDIT :
this is the code 
(Note: I'm writing a "biometric recognition system based on ear" and the database is data extracted from images1 to 5). This is the classification section of the code:

```
Nbcoordinates = vertcat(BEcell{:,1});
Necoordinates = vertcat(BEcell{:,2});

import DATA.txt.*; %     import our data set


for i=1:5

    token1 = 0; token2 = 0; token3 = 0; token4 = 0; token5 = 0; token6 = 0; token7 = 0;

    if(VarName1(i, 1) == V{1,1}(1,2) && VarName3(i, 1) == V{1,2}(1,2) &&   VarName5(i,1)     == V{1,3}(1,2) && VarName2(i,1) == V{1,1}(1,3) && VarName4(i,1)  ==   V{1,2}(1,3) && VarName6(i,1) == V{1,3}(1,3))



        %   Check number of endings for each component
        numberofendings =  strread(VarName10{i,1}, '%d', 'delimiter', '|');

        for j=1:size(Ne,1)

            if(numberofendings(j,1)~=Ne(j,1))
                    break;
            end
        end  
            if(j >= size(Ne,1))
                token1 = 1;                
            end


        % check number of bifurcations for each components
         numberofbifurcations =  strread(VarName11{i,1}, '%d', 'delimiter', '|');

        for j=1:size(Nb,1)

            if(numberofbifurcations(j,1) ~= Nb(j,1))
                    break;
            end

        end

            if(j >= Nb)
               token2  = 1;                
            end



        %   Check Intersections1,2,3  Cordinates
        Intercoordinate1 =  strread(VarName7{i,1}, '%f', 'delimiter', '|');
        m = 1;
        for j=1:NI1

            if((Intersection1(j, 1) ~= Intercoordinate1(m,1)) || (Intersection1(j, 2) ~= Intercoordinate1(m+1,1)))
                break;
            end
            m = m + 2;
        end
        if(j >= NI1)
            token3 = 1;                
        end



        Intercoordinate2 =  strread(VarName8{i,1}, '%f', 'delimiter', '|');
        m = 1;
        for j=1:NI2

            if((Intersection2(j, 1) ~= Intercoordinate2(m,1)) || (Intersection2(j, 2) ~= Intercoordinate2(m+1,1)))
                break;
            end
            m = m + 2;

        end
        if(j >= NI2)
            token4 = 1;                
        end






        Intercoordinate3 =  strread(VarName9{i,1}, '%s', 'delimiter', '|');
        m = 1;
        for j=1:NI3

            bi1 = cell2mat(Intercoordinate3(m, 1));
            bi2 = cell2mat(Intercoordinate3(m + 1, 1));
            if((Intersection3(j, 1) ~= str2num(bi2)) || (Intersection3(j, 2) ~= str2num(bi2)))
                break;
            end
            m = m + 2;
        end
        if(j >= NI3)
            token5 = 1;                
        end


         % Check endings coordinate of each component

        Endcoor =  strread(VarName12{i,1}, '%d', 'delimiter', '|');
        m = 1;
        for j=1:sum(Ne)
            en1 = Endcoor(m, 1);
            en2 = Endcoor(m + 1, 1);
            if((Necoordinates(j, 1) ~= en1) || (Necoordinates(j, 2) ~= en2))
                break;
            end
            m = m + 2;
        end
        if(j >= sum(Ne))
            token6 = 1;                
        end




        % check bifurcation coordinates of each component

        Bifcoor =  strread(VarName13{i,1}, '%d', 'delimiter', '|');
        m = 1;
        for j=1:sum(Nb)
            en1 = Bifcoor(m, 1);
            en2 = Bifcoor(m + 1, 1);
            if((Nbcoordinates(j, 1) ~= en1) || (Nbcoordinates(j, 2) ~= en2))
                break;
            end
            m = m + 2;
        end
        if(j >= sum(Nb))
            token7 = 1;                
        end





        if(token1 ==1 && token2 == 1 && token3== 1 && token4 == 1 && token5 == 1 && token6== 1 && token7==1 )
            disp(['This image is a member of Class ',num2str(i)]);
            break;
        end

    end


end


if(token1 == 0 || token2 == 0 || token3 == 0 || token4 == 0 || token5 == 0 || token6== 0 || token7==0)
    disp('Doesn;t exist in the data base ');
 end


 end
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code?

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: I don't get an error after running the code. the problem is variables like var1 that are assigned values by strread won't appear in workspace so typing them into command window gives me an error . also I don't get the correct result. I get 'Doesn't exist in the data base' every time, whatever the image input.

Comment: There is no `var1` in your code.

Comment: Var1 is an example mentioned in the comments above the code.

Comment: For example when I write numberofendings there is an error.

Comment: that means `if(VarName1(i, 1) == V{1,1}(1,2) && VarName3(i, 1) == V{1,2}(1,2) &&   VarName5(i,1)     == V{1,3}(1,2) && VarName2(i,1) == V{1,1}(1,3) && VarName4(i,1)  ==   V{1,2}(1,3) && VarName6(i,1) == V{1,3}(1,3))` is not entered or your tokens are allways 0.